# can not connect to mariadb server using dbeaver

Tags: mysql, raspbian, dbeaver, mariadb-10.3

I have installed and running MariaDB server on a raspberry 4. I am trying to connect with Dbeaver but i am unsuccessful.

Hosting db details:

1. Raspbian: GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
2. mariadb: Server version: 10.3.34-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 Raspbian 10

Client access:

1. Dbeaver: Version 22.1.5.202208211008
2. phpmyadmin

Now as you see, I have installed phpmyadmin as well and I can successfully connect to host. Also I can ssh remote connect.
However Dbeaver refuses to connect and  times out.

What I have tried so far:

1. I have configured mariadb in 50-server.cnf to bind to 0.0.0.0
2. I have added an `admin` user account in mysql with all rights and is stated as admin@192.168.1.x, where the ip is the remote pc's ip with the Dbeaver.
3. I have tried adding also "admin"@"%"

What should I troubleshoot next?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, after some tries, was that I went to Dbeaver connection settings/SSH/ and ticked the use SSH tunnel.In Settings I filled the server details and pi user and password.
Testing and connection was successful after some questions/answers about creating a key and a couple of directories.
I wend back to the connection and I was able to expand the connection view tree with Table/Views/etc
I am not sure why I needed the SSH tunnel to connect. It was not stated to any tutorial I used. Maybe someone in the community can help with this.